# kernel reports lots of "scsi parity error" / DID_BAD_TARGET errors

Tags: hard-disk

This is for an aging mechanical SATA drive.

Sample of the log:

```
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 00 69 00 00 00 48 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 16804096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 71 fc e9 00 00 00 48 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1912400128 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=13s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 23 82 a1 f0 00 00 08 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 595763696 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 53 04 00 38 00 00 08 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1392771128 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 53 04 00 38 00 00 08 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1392771128 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 53 04 00 38 00 00 08 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1392771128 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 53 04 00 38 00 00 08 00
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 01 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 3 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 3, async page read
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 4 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4, async page read
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 5, async page read
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 6, async page read
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 7, async page read
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1, async page read
```

this is not the boot drive, just a storage drive. System refused to boot anyway (infinite timeout waiting for the device, due to `x-systemd.device-timeout=0` options in fstab I think). Booted into a thumb drive, and was able to mount the drive, but ls output showed some ????? garbled entries. access attempts caused errors to show up in the system log.

commented out the drive in fstab and rebooted, and system still refused to boot due to timeout on another filesystem which isn't on the drive, but another reboot got the system booted.

Answer (score 2):

"SCSI parity error" made me suspect that this might be a cable issue. I replaced the cable and the problem went away. Ran fsck (which took a while even though ext4 has a journal) and then an intensive read-only e2fsck -c, no errors so far.

Can't be sure it's actually the cable, and not some intermittent things expunged by simply moving things around.

Comment: Cable, connector, or external interference (first things to check when you get transport-level errors).